# Using the triangle inequality to prove that differentiability implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Here's a bit from an epsilon-delta proof that differentiability implies continuity:

> $$|f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h|\leq\epsilon|h|.$$  Thus by the triangle
>   inequality, $$|f(a+h)-f(a)|\leq|f'(a)h|+\epsilon|h|.$$

How did the author apply the triangle inequality here? It seems that the alternate triangle inequality has been used, and if so, 
$$| \space |f(a+h)-f(a)|-|f'(a)h|\space|\leq\epsilon|h|,$$ so how does the author know that the expression inside the outer pair of modulus signs on the LHS is positive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a zero before using the inequality, $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
\begin{align*}
  \abs{f(a+h) - f(a)} &= \abs{f(a+h) - f(a) - f'(a)h + f'(a)h}\\
         &\le \abs{f(a+h) - f(a) - f'(a)h} + \abs{f'(a)h}\\
         &\le \epsilon \abs h + \abs{f'(a)h}
\end{align*}